# Passing socket connection n python between threads/processes (multiprocessing)

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, multiprocessing

I am preparing new driver (that should work over TCP/IP) and I am having kind of issue.

The main idea is, that there will be two separated loops.

1. Loop binds on port and keeps listening for incoming connection requests. Once a request is accepted, it authorizes client, if authorized, passes his connection to second loop. After client is passed to second loop, it should continue in listening for incoming connections. If new client connects, it is passed to second loop, and so on..
2. Second loop takes connected client, and manages sending and receiving data with him. However, it also checks if there is not some new connection, and if so, it will close actual connection to client and use new one.

This should ensure that if client connection is lost, we do not have to wait  for timeout to get new connection (which is the case why I am creating this new driver). If new connection is activated, we just close the old one and continue communication with modem with much shorter break time.

Here is the code (simplified):

```
class SocketDriver(Process):

def __init__(self):
    Process.__init__(self)
    self.stop_event = Event()
    self.client = None
    self.addr = None
    self.client_queue = Queue()

def connection_manager(self):
    while not self.stop_event.is_set():
        try:
            log.info('Binding to %s on port: %s' % (self.atmel_name, self.port))
            self.socket_object.bind((self.ip, self.port))
            break
        except socket.error, e:
            if e.errno == errno.EADDRINUSE:
                log.error('Socket error: %s, re-trying' % e)
                time.sleep(5)
            else:
                log.exception('Unknown exception')
                break

    while not self.stop_event.is_set():
        self.socket_object.listen(5)
        log.info('Waiting for incoming connections')
        # This cannot be touched, because accept command wont pass until something connect
        client, addr = self.socket_object.accept()
        log.info('Accepted connection from %s:%s' % (addr[0], addr[1]))
        self.client_queue.put([client, addr])

def open(self, port, bootloader=False):
    """
    Open port and load drivers
    """
    self.socket_object = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    #start new thread takes 1st argument as a function name to be run, second is the tuple of arguments to the function.
    start_new_thread(self.connection_manager ,())

def run(self):
    """
    Loop throught FIFO structures, check for incomming packet,
    send to peripheral device, receive response and deliver it
    """
    log.info('Starting SocketDriver loop')

    while not self.stop_event.is_set():
        # Watchdog touch
        open(touchfile, 'w').close()

        #Check if there is new client available
        if not self.client_queue.empty():
            log.info('New client found!')
            if self.client != None:
                self.client.close()
            conn_data = self.client_queue.get()
            self.client = conn_data[0] 
            self.addr = conn_data[1]
            log.info('Connected to new client with address: %s:%s' % (self.addr[0], self.addr[1]))

        # Check if there is any new connection
        if self.client != None:
            log.info('Client found, checking queues')
            for out_queue, in_queue, driver_id in self.fifocom_list:

                while not self.stop_event.is_set():
                    if not out_queue.empty():
                        self.write_packet(atmel_packet, driver_id)

                    # Vycitame a spracujeme odpoved
                    ready = select.select([self.client], [], [], 1)
                    if ready[0]:
                        log.info('[%s] Reading', self.source_name)
                        atmel_packet = self.read_packet()

        time.sleep(0.1)
```

The basic idea is to keep listening for new connections while communicating with actually connected client.

However, when I put anything else into "self.client_queue", the "if not self.client_queue.empty():" works. However, when I put there client and address from "self.socket_object.accept()", it crushes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 266, in _feed
        send(obj)
TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, NoneType found
```

Could anyone please explain what is going on here? I have read that there is problem with moving opened socets between processes, but the thread is being run within one process.